# CSS: styling successors of an element

Tags: css, gtk3

#### What I'm searching

In CSS: 
`E ~ F { }` stands for *any F node which is preceded by an E node*.
I'm searching for *any E node which is **succeeded** by an F node*

Or in other words:
I want something like  of `E + F {}`, but

1. not style `F`, but `E`
2. style all `E` before `F`

#### Concrete problem

I have a list of sibling elements. Some of them can be `.selected`,  one of them could be `.focused`, some of them can be neither. If any sibling is `.focused`, all `.selected` siblings should style in a certain way.

Example situation

```
<row class="selected">        content1</row>
<row class="">                content2</row>
<row class="selected">        content3</row>
<row class="selected focused">content4</row>
<row class="">                content5</row>
<row class="selected">        content6</row>
<row class="">                content7</row>
```

In this example content1,3,4,6 should be styled in a certain way.

I have a solution for content4 and 6, but I can't find the solution for content1 and 3.

**Constraints:**

- I cannot use anything else but CSS
- I can only work with sibling elements
- This is for Gtk's CSS, but I guess the solution is the same as in usual CSS

Comment: Doesn’t exist, might eventually. The normal solution is to add a class to the parent.

Comment: Could I like somehow add a temporal class to the parent within from the `focused` element *in CSS*?

Comment: No. There’s ~no way for an element to affect which rules are applied to anything before it in the tree (in the preorder traversal sense) in pure CSS.

Answer (score -2):

QUE: `E ~ F { }` stands for any F node which is preceded by an E node.
I'm searching for any E node which is succeeded by an F node

ANS: You are right but `E ~ F { }` this is only working with an element, not with the class for that you need to use dot `.` like `.selected.focused{ }` .

```css
.selected {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}
.selected.focused{
  background: green;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <row class="selected"> content1</row>
  <row class=""> content2</row>
  <row class="selected"> content3</row>
  <row class="selected focused">content4</row>
  <row class=""> content5</row>
  <row class="selected"> content6</row>
  <row class=""> content7</row>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer will not help with the problem. In the question E and F are variables for Elements.